# AngularJS directive image flickers on any scope update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am getting data from websocket. In that data I have lastEmplyeeID that I use to find employee pic in the img folder and display via directive. Unfortunately, any time some part of the controller scope changes (e.g. , the image flickers.

Directive:

```
myDirectives.directive('headshot', function($http) {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
        lastID: '@lastid'
    },
    template: '<img ng-src="{{imgSrc}}" class="headshot">',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        attrs.$observe('lastid', function(id) {

            scope.id = id;
            var src = 'img/nophoto.png';
            scope.imgSrc = (src);

                var url = 'photo/photo.aspx';

                //get name of the image based on employee id
                $http.get(url + '?id=' + scope.id)
                        .success(function(data) {
                            var src = 'img/' + data;
                            scope.imgSrc = (src);
                        })
                        .error(function(error) {                           
                        });              
        })
    }
};
});
```

View:

```
 <div id="imageWrapper">
    <headshot lastid="{{lastID}}"></headshot>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
myControllers.controller('MyCtrl',
    [
        '$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', 'webSocketService', 
        function($scope, $rootScope, $http, webSocketService) {
            $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;

            var data = {};

            //get data from socket
            webSocketService.getData();
            $rootScope.$on('broadcast', function() {

                data = webSocketService.message;
                $scope.eventState = data.event.eventState;
                $scope.lastID = $scope.eventState.lastEmployeeID;

                $scope.groups = data.event.groups; //when groups change, the picture of last employee flickers

            });
        }]);
```

Comment: What browsers have you tried this on? Does it affect all of them? Is this a subset of your code or does the code above also show the error if run by itself?

Comment: @amccormack I'm having the same problem on scope update, but the flickering is only noticable in Linux Google Chrome. Flickering is unnoticable / not present at all in OS X Chrome, Linux Firefox.

Comment: I am using Chrome. It is part of the requirements. There is no error shown in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce the flicker with the code provided, but there are a few things you may want to check or do:

1. Make sure nothing else is broadcasting on 'broadcast.'
2. Make sure a parent DOM element isn't forcing your headshot to refresh when data within the controller changes.
3. Perhaps refactor your directive to:

   ```
    myDirectives.directive('headshot', function($http) {
       return {
           restrict: 'AE',
           scope: {
               lastID: '@lastid'
           },
           template: '<img ng-src="{{imgSrc}}" class="headshot">',
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

               var src = 'img/nophoto.png';
               scope.imgSrc = (src);
               var last_id = -1;

               attrs.$observe('lastid', function(id) {
                   if ( last_id !== id ) {
                       //get name of the image based on employee id
                       $http.get('photo/photo.aspx?id=' + id).success(function(data) {
                           src = 'img/' + data;
                           scope.imgSrc = (src);
                       }).error(function(error) {                           
                           src = 'img/nophoto.png';
                           scope.imgSrc = (src);                
                       });
                       last_id = id;              
                   }
               })
           }
       };
   });
   ```

There is some chance that your flicker is caused by scope.imgSrc getting reset to "img/nophoto.png" briefly before the http service is able to load in the proper image.  Additionally, you should maintain some state and check to make sure that the new lastid is actually different than the previous value (will also prevent extraneous http calls).  This refactor should prevent that, although I don't actually see that as the cause of your problem since if I understand your problem correctly, lastid shouldn't actually be changing in the flickering cases.  If you are complaining about a flicker when the employee image *should* change, then this should fix your problem.

Comment: Websocket is always broadcasting. Flickering happens once it broadcast new info e.g if something in `$scope.groups` changed image will flicker even if `$scope.lastID` still the same.

Comment: Can you, please, give me a pointer of what should I do so that parent DOM element will not force headshot to refresh within the controller changes? Thank you